# How to specify the time zone and time format in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

I want to output the time of "+08:00", but when I call the `now()` function, it shows UTC time.

As follows:

```sql
select now();
+-----------------------------+
| now()                       |
+-----------------------------+
| 2023-04-28T07:07:29.421263Z |
+-----------------------------+
```

How to specify the time zone and time format in CnosDB?